# php mysql search description for keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, search-engine

I am creating a website that users upload images and write a description for it.
I want to allow the users to be able to search for description they have in mind of an image which they want to retrieve.

At first I decided to convert the description entered by the user while uploading the image into keywords and link the keywords to the image, in this case when the users performs a search for a description later on the description they enter will be converted to keywords and  somehow synonyms will be generated for the keywords which will all e search against the keywords in the DB.

Recently I read about mysql Full-text search. I created a table with descriptions and image ids and tried couple of queries using the full text search feature, It seems to be returning no results on most searches due to word length limit and stopwords.
Here is my test query:

```
SELECT * FROM descriptions WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('same' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

There is an entry in the table with a description containing the keyword 'same' but no results are returned.

My Question is is it better to use 'LIKE %keywords%' on the description table or use FTS on the description table or stick with the keyword table approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LIKE you have three approaches.

1) If it contains all the words in the same order (Keywords: One airplane)

```
SELECT * FROM descriptions WHERE description LIKE('%One airplane%');
```

2) If it contains all the words but ther order doesn't matter

```
SELECT * FROM descriptions WHERE description LIKE('%One%') AND description LIKE('% airplane%');
```

3) If it contains some of the words

```
SELECT * FROM descriptions WHERE description LIKE('%One%') OR description LIKE('% airplane%');
```

Now you can choose how strict do you want to be with the searches.

If you want to go with the second or third implementation you will be spliting the string with the keywords by "space" and adding a like for each item in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does your answer mean that in this case it is better to use LIKE rather than the FTS or keyword table approach I mentioned in my question?

Comment: If you are not an expert in MySQL it will be easier for you to understand how it works. FTS is more complicated than LIKE.
In the end you will probably be able to do the same with both, but you will invest a lot more time to make it work with FTS

Comment: thanks, is it possible to achieve a ranking of some sort as offered by FTS using LIKE ?